# How can I put the animate transition of my javascript into my css?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate, portability

I'm trying to make my javascript more portable by placing its animation values in the css page. I'm hoping this change will allow me to update the animation values inside my css page as opposed to my javascript. I can't seem to get it to work when I try to make the change.

here is my working code...

//javascript that animates a div to grow in size

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".someContent").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
    if ($(this).hasClass('highLight')) {
    $(this).animate({"width": "80%", "height": "200px", "opacity": "1"}, "fast");
} else {
    $(this).animate({"width": "30%", "height": "60px", "opacity": "1"}, "fast");
}
});
})
```

//the css that goes with the javascript above

```
.someContent {
width: 30%;
margin-left: 100px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: left;
padding: 0px;
height: 60px;
}

.highLight {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
border: 2px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: top 0.2s;
transition: top 0.2s;
}
```

//I thought this code would work to change the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".someContent").on("click", ".vacation", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
});
})
```

//and maybe change the css in this fashion to handle the animation

```
.someContent {
width: 30%;
margin-left: 100px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: left;
padding: 0px;
height: 60px;
-webkit-transition: top 0.2s;
transition: top 0.2s;
}

.highLight {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
width: 60%;
height: 300px;
border: 2px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: top 0.2s;
transition: top 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: this is the example code for css animation 
[example @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yexrzd17/)

Comment: yeah I know how to animate in css, just trying to write jQuery code that animates but allows me to still update the values in the css page